# Dynamic data from mySQL to iPhone

Tags: iphone, mysql, xcode

I have a mySQL database with table 'users' and table 'GPS'.

In the 'GPS' table the coordinates for the users GPS units are stored and updated every minute.

I need to make an iPhone app where the user can log in and then see all his GPS units in a table view and a map view.

How would you advice me to go about this?

I was thinking I could make PHP fetch the data and then read it on the iPhone, but I am guessing there would be some security risks.

I could also store the users information on the iPhone, but then the coordinates would be static, unless info on the iPhone gets updated every minute like the real database.

Answer (score 0):

create a webservice (maybe in php) with a well-defined interface (it is also possible to make this secure) and then access that webservice from your iphone.

A possible solution would be a "restful-webservice" with xml communication. The your iPhone only has to connect to that webserver with maybe some authentification and then parse the resulting xml to get the actual obj-c objects which then can be displayed in a tableview or mapview.

**edit:** or a bit simpler: create a php-file which accesses the desired data from your mysql which is protected via ssl which gets username/password as post-parameters which then results in a desired xml. But take into consideration that this option is quite ok but not really save but in the end your problem is just to secure your webservice.

comment: a direct connection of an iPhone-App to a MySql-Database is never a good idea.